# Why is my subtract function working in a static context when I haven't used the @staticmethod decorator?

Tags: python, static-methods

So, I did not know what static methods were so i searched it up and i made this

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    @staticmethod
    def add(x,y):
        result = x + y
        return result

    def sub(x,y):
        result = x-y
        return result

print(Calculator.add(3,4))
print(Calculator.sub(5,7))
```

My question is why does the sub method works in a static context even without the @staticmethod decorator? Does it have something to do with the fact that the sub method doesn't use self.num1 or self.num2 or am I just implementing this wrong?

Comment: There is no "static context" Python != Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the difference because you didn't instantiate an object (`Calculator` is the class, `Calculator()` is an object).

See the following snippet:

```
class Calculator:
    @staticmethod
    def add(x,y):
        result = x + y
        return result

    def sub(x,y):
        result = x-y
        return result

print(Calculator().add(3,4))
print(Calculator().sub(5,7))
```

The call to `add` will work, but not that to `sub` that will receive an extra first parameter.

###### another example to illustrate your question in the comments:

```
class Calculator:
    @staticmethod
    def add(x,y):
        result = x + y
        return result
    def sub(self,x,y):
        result = x-y
        return result

print(Calculator().add(3,4))
print(Calculator().sub(5,7))
print(Calculator.sub(None,5,7))
```

Comment: shouldn't my program still raise an error as I tried to call sub from a static context?

Comment: No because there is no object, so no implicit reference to the object passed to the function.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. There is no static context here, just a function. `staticmethod` will only make sense in the **instance** as without it, calling the method will implicitly pass a reference to the instance. If `sub` was defined as `sub(self, x, y)` you'd need to pass a dummy parameter on the class, not the instance (see update)